# What is a GADT skolem?

Tags: types, gadt

Long ago, I got [an error message in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36002541/1393162) informing me that I had a GADT skolem. I googled but only found very abstract descriptions of GADT skolems, nothing with an example that illustrated in a realistic context why the concept is needed. I found a workaround to the error but never understood what the trouble. Could you please explain, with a realistic, practical, but hopefully simple example, what is a GADT skolem?

Comment: When I saw this question in chat I thought I was in RPG.SE and this is a DnD question

Comment: @Seggan Skolems, not golems.

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719435/what-are-skolems) may help

Answer (score 7):

Say you have an existential type, like this example in Haskell:

```
-- | A task that will produce a value of type @a@.
data Task a where

  -- | A value of hidden type @t@,
  -- which will be used as input to the task.
  Task :: t -> (t -> IO a) -> Task a
```

When you write a function on such a type, you use pattern-matching to bring the type variable `t` into scope:

```
runTask :: Task a -> IO a
runTask (Task x f) = f x  -- Here, ‘x :: t’
```

Since `t` is existentially quantified, it should remain abstract—`runTask` can’t see what type `t` is.

One way for a compiler to enforce this is by creating a fresh type constant for it, which doesn’t match any other type. This is sometimes referred to as a “skolem constant” or “skolem type variable”, because this process is related to *skolemisation*, named after logician Thoralf Skolem. (However, typical compilers don’t bother to actually transform the type into skolem normal form, so it may be a bit of a misnomer.)

You may see mention of these variables in an error message if you inadvertently try to use such a type variable outside of its *scope*. It may be easier to see what this scope is, precisely, if we make it explicit using continuation-passing style:

```
withTask ::
  Task a ->
  (forall t. t -> (t -> IO a) -> r) ->
  r
withTask (Task x f) k = k x f
```

And here’s an example `Task`:

```
task :: Task String
task =
  Task
    (42 :: Int)
    \x -> print x *> pure (show x)
```

Now, the function we supply as the continuation `k` cannot make any assumptions about the type `t`:

```
-- Error: can’t deduce ‘t ~ Int’
main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- withTask task \x f ->
    if x == (42 :: Int) then pure "beans" else f x
  putStrLn result
```

And also, its return type `r` cannot mention `t`:

```
-- Error: ‘t’ would escape its scope.
stealSecrets task = withTask task \x _f -> x
```

Because, in the type of `withTask`, `r` is also used as the final return type, which is entirely *outside* of the scope where `t` is defined (namely, `(forall t. …)`). This is also the feature that lets the `ST` monad enforce the invariant that no `STRef` escapes the scope of a call to `runST`, whose type is `(forall s. ST s a) -> a`.